# Mysql dump: Copying MYI files in production is safe?

Tags: mysql

Want to copy some big tables which are used very often from main server to local server in production mode ofc.

Is it safe?

Some suggestions, tools are welcome. :)

Comment: Why don't you use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html ?

Comment: `mysqldump` can be much slower, but it is more likely to produce a consistent result.

Comment: Wise words by pkaeding and worthy of an up-vote

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing from asking about MYI tables that all of your tables are MyISAM tables and not InnoDb ones. Each MyISAM table is made up of three files: .frm, .MYD and .MYI they contain the structure, data and index respectively.

People advise against copying these raw files from running systems but I've found that as long as you're sure nothing's writing to the tables then copying them works fine (I've done this more times than I care to remember).

If you're doing this on a replica then just stop replication on the slave before copying. If it's just a single server or the master I'd recommend running `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` before you start copying files, this will prevent any process from writing to the tables. When you're done release the lock with `UNLOCK TABLES`.

I would always recommend doing a `CHECK TABLE` on the tables you've copied in this manner. I *think* this is what I've used in the past `mysqlcheck --all-tables --fast --auto-repair`

If you're using LVM on the server then taking an LVM snapshot could be another way of getting hold of a clean snapshot.

If you're going to be doing this regularly I'd recommend either using replication to keep the local server up to date or to setup a slave which you can use for taking backups (as it's not the main database there's no problem with you stopping it, dumping tables, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's alright if you

- Shut the mysql server down cleanly before you copy the files, or at least take a global read lock
- Take the .frm .MYI and .MYD files at the same time.
- Have identical my.cnf and run the same MySQL version on each system

So it's basically ok, but not necessarily a good idea.

If you have different versions of mysql (You can only generally move to a more recent version, not an older one), or are running with a significantly different my.cnf (i.e. any of the fulltext indexing parameters differ, and you have fulltext indexes), you may need to rebuild the table. Rebuilding the table can be done on the destination server with ALTER TABLE blah ENGINE=MyISAM; this might still be a bit faster than a mysqldump / restore.

Comment: Good advice but... I don't think that there are many config options that will cause problems with the move and moving between minor versions should be fine. the only problems I've seen were with big version differences (i.e. 4.x to 5.0) where the MyISAM storage engine format had changed.

Comment: There are a lot of edge-cases. Particularly if you use fulltext indexing. In some cases it can result in a table which superficially works but has subtle structural problems.